# Unable to login after installing KDE

Tags: unity, kde

I had a Unity environment on my laptop and yesterday I decide to change it to kde, so I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install kde
```

and installation was correct, I choose lightdm in menuconfig as default login shell/service. After reboot, I have preety Ubuntu kde login screen, but when I type login and password lightdm dont pass me to desktop, and X-Server reset itself, and again I see a a KDE login window. (I have option to choose Unity, gnome, kde unity-2D all of them restarts X11)

Is possible to fix that and use kde and lightdm? Or I must remove one of them? 
My goal is to dont use Unity, but I dont want reinstall by ubuntu to xbuntu or something similar.

Comment: ps. I tried to apt-get install lightdm --reinstall but it don't help me

Comment: I would recommend installing kubuntu-desktop via sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop  to make sure all the dependancies are configured and setup.